# What is the logic in cs:go style reels?

Tags: javascript, python, php

I've been stuck in my head for a long time, but I'm looking for an idea that will be more acceptable than the solution I found myself, I'm curious about your thoughts.

You know the wheel of luck, every object has an equal probability of coming out. If there are 20 objects, there is a 5% chance that one of these objects will come off the wheel.

The rationale for this is simple and easy to design.

However, if the probability of some objects appearing on this wheel is 1%, the probability of others is 5% and the probability of others is 60%, how do we design this.

My solution that I found but consumes a lot of power is as follows.

dividing the wheel into 100 parts and separating 60 divisions into 1 product, 1 division into 1 product and 5 divisions into 1 products.

[image]

But this is a very simple and problematic solution.

I would be grateful if you tell me your ideas, what is the logic under how the people who make the systems I mentioned design it.

Comment: The term for this is "weighted probability". Google it.

Comment: Python has built-in functions for it in the `random` module.

Comment: @Barmar When I did a search on the "weighted probability" word you gave. I found this class. https://github.com/ihor/Nspl And it looks like it will do my job pretty well. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Python:

```py
import random

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
weights = [10, 1, 5]
result = random.choices(letters, weights, k=50)
print(''.join(sorted(result)))
```

The 50 is the amount of random choices to generate.

An example output would be `aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbccccccccccccccc`

Documentation for the random module is at https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html